# how to Use html to insert comma seperated values into a numpy array for prediction

Tags: python, html, numpy, machine-learning

I tried

```html
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="n1"></td>
```

to take input.

```
17.99,10.38,122.8,1001,0.1184,0.2776,0.3001,0.1471,0.2419,0.07871,1.095,0.9053,8.589,153.4,0.006399,0.04904,0.05373,0.01587,0.03003,0.006193,25.38,17.33,184.6,2019,0.1622,0.6656,0.7119,0.2654,0.4601,0.1189
```

I feed that into a numpy array in `view.py`.

```
np.array((request.GET['n1']))
```

But I am getting the following error message.

```
ValueError at /prediction/output
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=['17.99,10.38,122.8,1001,0.1184,0.2776,0.3001,0.1471,0.2419,0.07871,1.095,0.9053,8.589,153.4,0.006399,0.04904,0.05373,0.01587,0.03003,0.006193,25.38,17.33,184.6,2019,0.1622,0.6656,0.7119,0.2654,0.4601,0.1189'].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

`view.py`  (`v1 = np.array((request.GET['n1']))` is on the 8th line)

```py
def output(request):
    dff = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Downloads\data.csv')
    y = dff['diagnosis'].values
    x = dff.drop('diagnosis', axis=1).values
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.40)
    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    v1 = np.array((request.GET['n1']))

pred = model.predict([v1])
    pred1 = ""
    if pred==[1]:
        pred1 = "positive"
    else:
        pred1 = "negative"
return render(request, 'prediction.html', {"predictResult":**pred1**})
```

`prediction.html` (the 6th line is to get the input)

```html
<div>
    <form action="output">
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Pregnancies</td>
               <td align="left"><input type="text" name="n1"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
     <input type="submit">
    </form>

    Result:{{ predictResult }}
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to store numbers or strings in your numpy array?

Comment: trying to store numbers  17.99,10.38,122.8,1001,0.1184,0.2776,0.3001,0.1471,0.2419,0.07871,1.095,0.9053,8.589,153.4,0.006399,0.04904,0.05373,0.01587,0.03003,0.006193,25.38,17.33,184.6,2019,0.1622,0.6656,0.7119,0.2654,0.4601,0.1189

Comment: 30 seperate numbers

Answer (score 0):

The error message show that `v1` is a numpy array with a single entry. That entry is a string with your comma-separated list. You will need to split that up into the individual numbers. You'll probably want to do something like this:

```py
v1 = np.array([float(num) for num in request.GET['n1'].split(",")])
```

The message also mentions the shape of the array, so you will need to reshape it according to your case (just follow what the error message says).

Comment: this code is giving me output as below but i wanted comma sepetare values in either integer or float.  1.454e+01 2.754e+01 9.673e+01 6.588e+02 1.139e-01 1.595e-01 1.639e-01 7.364e-02 2.303e-01 7.077e-02 3.700e-01 1.033e+00 2.879e+00 3.255e+01 5.607e-03 4.240e-02 4.741e-02 1.090e-02 1.857e-02 5.466e-03 1.746e+01 3.713e+01 1.241e+02 9.432e+02 1.678e-01 6.577e-01 7.026e-01 1.712e-01 4.218e-01 1.341e-01

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by comma separated in this case. Numpy stores data as an array, which doesn't have a delimiter (like commas).